# Malloc-ating inside a Function vs malloc-ating in Main

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have a struct that contains an int pointer

```
    struct mystruct {
      int *myarray;
    };
```

I want to make a function that mallocates for mystruct and also initializes myarray. But, when I try to access an element of myarray, I get a seg. fault

```
    void myfunction(struct mystruct *s, int len) {
        s = malloc(sizeof(mystruct));
        s->myarray = malloc(sizeof(int) * len);
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
            s->myarray[i] = 1;
        }
    }

    main() { 
        struct mystruct *m;
        myfunction(m, 10);
        printf("%d", m->myarray[2]); ////produces a segfault
    }
```

However, mallocating m in main seemed to solve my problem.
Revised Code:

```
    void myfunction(struct mystruct *s, int len) {
        int i;
        s->myarray = malloc(sizeof(int) * len); 
        for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
            s->myarray[i] = 1;
        }
     }

     main() {
         struct mystruct *m = malloc(sizeof(mystruct)); //this was in myfunction 
         myfunction(m,10);
         printf("%d", m->myarray[2]); ///Prints out 1 like I wanted
     }
```

Why did the 2nd attempt work and why did the first attempt not work?

Comment: You seem to be missing a parenthesis here... `s = malloc(sizeof(mystruct);`

Comment: added the parenthesis

Comment: The correct definition is `int main(void)`, not `main()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the first version assigns the result of malloc to a parameter, which effectively a local variable; the assigned value vanishes when the function returns

So, an alternative is to pass to the function a pointer to the location where you want to store the result of malloc. This is named `pps` in the code below. At the beginning of the function we do the malloc and assign to a local variable `s`. Then we do things with `s`. Then, just before the function exits, we assign the local variable `s` to the location pointed to by the parameter `pps`. `*pps = s;`

```
void myfunction(struct mystruct **pps, int len) { // note double "**" 
        struct mystruct *s = malloc(sizeof(mystruct);
        s->myarray = malloc(sizeof(int) * len);
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
            s->myarray[i] = 1;
        }
        *pps = s; // now pass the alloc'ed struct back to main through parameter pps
    }
```

Now, back in `main` we pass `&m` to the function. This passes a pointer to `m` to the function. When the function returns, the local variable `m` holds the value returned by malloc and passed through the parameter `pps`.

```
main() { 
    struct mystruct *m;
    myfunction(&m, 10); // PASS THE ADDRESS OF m, not m itself
    printf("%d", m->myarray[2]); // this will work now
}
```

Comment: "never made it back to `main`" seems unclear. The problem is that the first version assigns the result of `malloc` to a parameter, which  effectively a local variable; the assigned value vanishes when the function returns.

Comment: @KeithThompson, yes your explanation is much clearer than mine. Hopefully the OP will read your comment and it will make sense to him.

Comment: Feel free to steal my comment and use it to update your answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson,ok I did that and added some more explanation. Feel free to edit. Thanks.